# Can hash output be dangerous for SQL Queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, hash

There was a question about using stripslashes and mysql_real_escape_string on a password before hashing it and storing it. And the stripping or escaping before the hashing isn't necessary as the special characters don't carry meaning to the hashing function.

However, is it possible that certain hash results may create dangerous SQL queries?

I realize  that with a sufficient hash and a salt that there's such a small chance of this happening intentionally, but would it still be a good practice to run a strip and escape on the hashed results?

Comment: Unless you're maintaining some sort of legacy application that needs to run on older versions of PHP, you should be using either mysqli or PDO (with their binding syntaxes).  Then this question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @nsanders It's not always up to us what we use.

Comment: @Chris there are actually plans to deprecate and eventually discontinue the older mysql extension in favor of mysqli, so if you are making new software you may as well use the preferred method and ensure your environment provides that.

Comment: @Chris That's very true.  As long as you realize that from a technical standpoint the legacy mysql_* functions are not what you should be using.  Hopefully, the decision makers will come to their senses sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Pelshoff currently fighting the battle of updating old code base versus need to develop new features.

Comment: @Chris most of luck to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be overzealous and unnecessary to do so. Hashing functions don't output any quotes that could introduce a SQL injection vulnerability. Also, you shouldn't really have to use both `stripslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Just use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

**Example**
Not that I am condoning the use of MD5, but from its Wikipedia page:

> An MD5 hash is typically expressed as a 32-digit hexadecimal number.

Hexidecimal numbers should never pose a problem with SQL injections because they just consist of `/[0-9a-f]/`. If you search for the hashing function that you're using you should find something similar. You don't need to sanitize the hash. You should be safe!

Comment: This is not entirely true. If magic quotes is enabled, it is a good practice to use `stripslashes` on GET/POST arguments. This should however happen once at the beginning of the script for all arguments at the same time.

Comment: @Niklas True. But if magic quotes are enabled, you need to find a new host or update your PHP.ini (if you can).

Answer (score 3):

The result of a hash function is a number. To my knowledge, most if not all php hash functions return the number in hex. There can be no danger of an unsafe string result from a hash function.

However, it is always a good practice to escape everything you put into a query - or even better, use parameterized queries.

Comment: I did miss the part about them giving back HEX, which would exclude all possible special characters. Thanks.